# Moderator message pages aren't limited in width

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Somebody misread the markdown formatting help and used a four indent space on a rather long paragraph in [this moderator message](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/message/92#92). This screwed up the body of the page, which is now 6989 pixels wide. For reference, that's slightly wider than this handy equation:

> [image: Quartic equations]
>   <sub>[Click to embiggen in all of its glory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPGS0.png)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This was fixed when the Moderator messages page was overhauled recently:

[image: Mod message with fixed preformatted/code formatting]

<sub>*This is not the original mod message, no.
This is a tribute!*</sub>

Comment: I don't believe you; I wasn't there. This is just a matter of opinion.